# Applications in black and white

Tags: 20.04, gnome, graphics, xorg, themes

I have been using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS for about 4 months

I started to change it's settings and stuff -
**but in a while after logging in apps started to behave in a strange way.**

#### For example

- When I open an application, it appears in **black and white** , although the background, the dock and icons are colored. See the picture

[image: File menu]

and the stranger thing is that it returns to **normal after some time**
. Any idea about the problem ?
EDIT :
I'm adding the neofetch in a two states (focus on the color of the terminal)
Here is the first neofetch: [image: first neofetch] while the terminal is black and white
and here is the second neofetch [image: second neofetch] while the everything looks fine
I hope it can help you figure the problem

Comment: Difficult to help as it will depend on what you changed on the system. It is also not clear in your picture what is wrong, and what you expect to see. Perhaps add a picture of the normal appearance as well.

Comment: i didn't do anything just some custom themes and in the picture the window that's opened is in black and white while the background is in color

Comment: Did you keep a log of your actions?  If so, you can probably find the culprit by process of elimination.  Reverse changes that you made one by one to determine the cause of the problem.

Comment: Try checking if the 'high contrast' accessibility is enabled in the system settings.

Comment: Giving the output of `neofetch` will help people recognize the themes and customizations you have made. As Vanadium the information provided by you is less. Please [edit] accordingly.

Comment: alright i just added the neofetch in two states so that you can understand what's going on